# I am unfamiliar with Ubuntu on my Dell Mini (pre-installed)

Tags: ubuntu-netbook, troubleshooting

I got a Dell Mini that comes with Ubuntu. 
I am unfamiliar with Ubuntu and I do not know how I can use it. I have trouble connecting to the Internet and I do not know what apps are available. I am quite frustrated!

Can you give me information that will get me started to learn about Ubuntu?

Comment: Can you clarify your problem a bit?  Did something stop working that you were using, or do you need help getting acquainted with Ubuntu in the first place?

Comment: We can't help you when you don't give us specifics. Take a few minutes to [Gather information about your problems](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and for each issue open a [new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) so we can address each issue in turn.

Comment: We would be more than happy to help, if you are willing to slow down and help us to help you.

Comment: I edited your question's title to help you get some assistance :), now it's up to you to add the details ;)! If you need live assistance you can always head over to the ask ubuntu general chat room (right here on this site). Someone will almost always be there that can help you out ^^!

Answer (score 4):

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/user/bubblyonline#p/u/49/0JxoCXmAlRI) is a good introductory video tutorial to Ubuntu.  That youtube user has dozens of other tutorial videos as well.  He's using an older version of Ubuntu, but most of the basics are the same, assuming you aren't using the newest version (11.04), which releases in a couple days (April 28, 2011).  Version 11.04 uses the new Unity layout, which is pretty radically different, and much more akin to OS X.

Here is the [official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/) for Ubuntu.  It's much more in-depth (and maybe a little more work to wade through).  It will walk you through most of the basics.

In short, to get to places, you'll want to use the three menus in the upper-left of the screen, especially the "Applications" menu.  Under Applications > Internet you'll find firefox, which is the default web browser.  The Open Office programs will do the work you may be used to doing in MS Office (word processing, spreadsheets, etc.).  The last item in the Applications menu is the installer, where you can search for new programs and install them.

If you have a more specific problem than this, go ahead and edit your question (or ask a new one) and we'll be able to help further.

Comment: (meta) I've [proposed starting](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1272/should-we-put-together-a-basic-intro-to-ubuntu-faq) an "intro to ubuntu" faq/series of questions, too.  Seems like this could be a great resource for users new to Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

There is a big community about Ubuntu on the Dell Mini,
http://www.ubuntumini.com/

You can also join the community there.